# Pass ruby script file to rails console

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a way to pass ruby file, *foo.rb* to rails console. Expected results would be after console starts rails environment to run file.

Or any other way which would allow me to execute file in rails environment, triggered from command prompt.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I run a Ruby file in a Rails environment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757261/how-do-i-run-a-ruby-file-in-a-rails-environment)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

In the meantime, this solution has been supported.

```
rails r PATH_TO_RUBY_FILE
```

Much simpler now.

Comment: in which Rails versions?

Comment: I think 3+, I can confirm for 5.

Answer (score 202):

Actually, the simplest way is to run it with `load` inside the `rails console`

```
 load './path/to/foo.rb'
```

Comment: This works great. But unless I'm doing something wrong, you do not have access to objects created inside the script. Any way to do that? The use case is to set up some objects, then interactively explore them. Is that possible?

Comment: @DanBarron you can put in a debugger or binding.pry

Comment: This is just like a Lisp REPL +1

Comment: Noob help : ./path - is path relative to your rails project where your file resides.

Answer (score 97):

You can use

```
bundle exec rails runner "eval(File.read 'your_script.rb')"
```

UPDATE:

What we also have been using a lot lately is to load the rails environment from within the script itself. Consider `doit.rb`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require "/path/to/rails_app/config/environment"

# ... do your stuff
```

This also works if the script or the current working directory are not within the rails app's directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot that does a job! I am using Sublime Text 2 so now I will be able to trigger builds of rails classes and see output directly in IDE :)

Comment: script/runner "eval(File.read 'your_script.rb')" for rails 2.3 :)

Comment: you can use a similar pattern to run files inside the console: `f=File.new('path/to/file')` to run use: `f.rewind; eval f.readlines.join("\n");`

Comment: FYI you don't need the `eval(File.read ...)` part anymore. Rails accepts a Ruby file as an argument to `rails runner`: `Usage: rails runner [options] [<'Some.ruby(code)'> | <filename.rb>]`

Comment: Update- as per @HarisKrajina's answer below, looks like `rails r path/to/filename.rb` is functionally equivalent to the `bundle exec rails runner` command mentioned above.

Comment: See the last subsection under 1.6 for documentation here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-runner.

Answer (score 6):

Consider creating a rake task.

For code that I need to create records or support migrations, for example, I often create a rake task like that from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42498691/1038034). For example:

In `lib/tasks/example.rake`:

```
namespace :example do
  desc "Sample description you'd see if you ran: 'rake --tasks' in the terminal"
  task create_user: :environment do
    User.create! first_name: "Foo", last_name: "Bar"
  end
end
```

And then in the terminal run:

```
rake example:create_user
```

Answer (score 5):

```
script/console --irb=pry < test.rb > test.log
```

simple, dirty, and block the process at the end, but it does the job exactly like I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Of these approaches mentioned earlier, none seemed clean and ideal like you would expect a standalone script to run (not get eval-ed or piped via < redirection), but finally this works perfect for me:

(for Rails 3)

Insert at the top of your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

APP_PATH = File.expand_path(appdir = '/srv/staging/strat/fundmgr/config/application',  __FILE__)
require File.expand_path(appdir + '/../boot',  __FILE__)
require APP_PATH
# set Rails.env here if desired
Rails.application.require_environment!

# your code here...
```

Of course, set your own Rails app path in the APP_PATH line.

That way, I can avoid having to enter any interactive `irb` or `rails c` and can test my *script.rb* from the shell prompt, before eg. scheduling it in crontab.

It smoothly supports command-line parameters, too, and minimizes the levels of wrappers before getting to your code.

CREDIT (also shows a Rails 2 example)

http://zerowidth.com/2011/03/18/standalone-script-runner-bin-scripts-in-rails.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's the hack I'm using:

```
rr() {
    rails_root="$(bundle exec rails runner "puts Rails.root")"
    rp="$(relpath "$1" "$rails_root")"
    bundle exec rails runner "eval(File.read '$rp')"
}
relpath() {python -c "import os.path; print os.path.relpath('$1','${2:-$PWD}')";}
```

Example:

```
cd ~/rails_project/app/helpers
rr my_script.rb
```

Based on @moritz's answer here. I changed it, since the working directory for `File.read` is the Rails project root.

I know this is some serious heresy, using python to help a ruby script. But I couldn't find a `relpath` method built into ruby.

Credit: `relpath()` was taken from @MestreLion, [Convert absolute path into relative path given a current directory using Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564634/bash-convert-absolute-path-into-relative-path-given-a-current-directory#comment-12808306)