# execute multiple commands on console through unix shell

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell, unix, console

I am currently trying to figure out if it is possible to run multiple commends within one line on a rails console through Unix shell or within a ruby script.

For Example:

```
exec('echo p = Product.first;b = Billing.first|rails c')
```

When I tried something similar to the example, it would always try to execute the two commands before launching console.

Hope this make sense and appreciate any help I can get.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might consider making a rake task for this. It's a little more idiomatic.

Comment: Answer to your literal question: more quotes. But it's really a strange thing to do, executing rails console from shell from ruby, almost certainly an XY problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass ruby script file to rails console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313181/pass-ruby-script-file-to-rails-console)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do this

From a unix shell prompt:

```
echo 'p = Product.first; b = Billing.first' | rails c
```

From the rails console itself, or a ruby script I guess:

```
exec(%Q{echo 'p = Product.first; b = Billing.first' | rails c})
```

It's probably worth asking why you want to do this though. Could you use a [rake task](http://railsguides.net/how-to-generate-rake-task/)?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I haven't tried writing my own rake task before but it is something I should explore.  I was just kind of messing around do to my curiosity. Thanks again everyone for all the help!

Comment: My use case is to run essentially one-time-use commands, and the first code line is working well for me.